Can EXCEPT be used in prisma?
I'm trying to use EXCEPT in a Prisma project, but I don't see any documentation of it in the official site.
I need, for example:
SELECT * FROM TABLE_A
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM TABLE_B

Is that possible with Prisma?
I'm using a raw query right now. But with Prisma sentences it would be easier if I can use EXCEPT.

I face similar problem. I used something like below as an alternative as Prisma does not support using EXCEPT directly.
const result = await prisma.$queryRaw`
  SELECT * FROM TABLE_A
  EXCEPT
  SELECT * FROM TABLE_B
`;
console.log(result);

